# How to add elements of an array, based on a condition, in azure logic apps?

Tags: arrays, json, filter, logic, azure-logic-apps

I would like to add up the values of an array, based on a condition.

```
{ "name": "alfons", "value": 100, "condValue": "D90" }, 
{ "name": "alfons", "value": 300, "condValue": "D10" }, 
{ "name": "alfons", "value": 200, "condValue": "D90" }, 
{ "name": "max", "value": 600, "condValue": "D90" }, 
{ "name": "max", "value":100, "condValue": "D90" }
```

In relation to this example array I want to add the values if the conditional value and the name of an object match.
In this example my ideal output would be:

```
{ "name": "alfons", "value": 300, "condValue": "D90" }, 
{ "name": "alfons", "value": 300, "condValue": "D10" }, 
{ "name": "max", "value": 700, "condValue": "D90" }
```

[image]

What I did so far: I'm filtering the payload array (the real data I'm fetching is an array with about 700 elements) in a for each loop for the individual names. This array I filter again for the conditional Value in another for each loop (nested in the first one).

Now my question is how do I add the values up and compose a new array so it doesn't blow up in my face since I'm looping three times here.

My idea was to compose a json object everytime the loop finished and append it to an array variable, but i would again end up with tons of duplicates.

"Execute JavaScript Code" unfortunately isn't an option.

**Solution:**

I couldn't test the proposed solution with the *Advanced Data Operations* connector but it appears very sound.

I resolved the task with logic-app base functionality like this:

[logic app flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nDQP.png)

I start by looping through the names and filtering the payload for the current name.

Then I loop through each object in the payload array, writing the condValue of the current object into a variable *condValueContainer* and reset a sum variable to 0.
I open up a third loop, through the payload array again. Here I check the condValue of the current array object with the condValueContainer. If true, I increment the sum variable by the value of the current object.

The result is:

```
{ "name": "alfons", "value": 300, "condValue": "D90" },
{ "name": "alfons", "value": 300, "condValue": "D10" },
{ "name": "alfons", "value": 300, "condValue": "D90" },
{ "name": "max", "value": 700, "condValue": "D90" },
{ "name": "max", "value": 700, "condValue": "D90" },
```

So I just have to get rid of the duplicates.
I empty the payload array. Then I loop through the payloadSorted array. Whithin I check whether *payload* does not contain the current object of *payloadSorted*. If that's the case I append it to *payload*.

I end up with this result, as I needed it:

```
{ "name": "alfons", "value": 300, "condValue": "D90" },
{ "name": "alfons", "value": 300, "condValue": "D10" },
{ "name": "max", "value": 700, "condValue": "D90" },
```

This whole construct may be inefficient, especially when running somewhat bigger arrays. So I will probably come back to it to slim it down. For now I'm happy it's working.
If you have any suggestions on how to make this more efficient with logic-app base functionality please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, use the **Aggregate** operation in the **Advanced Data Operations** connector.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/advanceddataoperatio/

https://www.statesolutions.com.au/aggregate/

https://www.statesolutions.com.au/pricing/

***Note**: With the below, the `Data` variable is your data (as an array) that you provided.*

[image: Aggregate]

#### Result

[image: Result]

```
[
  {
    "name": "alfons",
    "condValue": "D10",
    "value": 300
  },
  {
    "name": "alfons",
    "condValue": "D90",
    "value": 300
  },
  {
    "name": "max",
    "condValue": "D90",
    "value": 700
  }
]
```

Comment: this looks pretty straight forward, thanks for the suggestion!
I ended up solving the task with logic app base functionality. I'll update the post shortly.